# How do I get an absolute positioned div to sit centred horizontally with a fixed div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to get a div(main) to sit centred withing another div(centre), the div(main) needs to be static as I don't want it to scroll but the div(centre) has to be absolute so it can sit on a separate div with an onclick function.

current HTML and css:

```
 <div className='meal_popup'>
                    <div className='meal_popupElement'>
                        <p>testing1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div onClick={this.mealOne_boxClickHandler} className='meal_popupBackground' />
                </div>

.meal_popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
}


.meal_popupElement {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 35rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    z-index: 2;

}

.meal_popupBackground {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Goal:
[image]
(this visually looks how I want but the problem is the whole div is clickable and only want that function on the background HTML and css:)

```
<div onClick={this.mealTwo_boxClickHandler} className='meal_background'>
                    <div>
                        <p>testing2</p>
                    </div>
                </div>


 .meal_background {
      position: fixed;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.6);
      z-index: 30;
    }

    .meal_background div {
      background: white;
      border-radius: 15px;
      height: 35rem;
      width: 100%;
      margin-left: 1rem;
      margin-right: 1rem;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
        0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    }
```

Comment: You can add position relative to the div instead of absolute. Then you can add text-align: center if its not a flex item and simply an  inline-block or on flex use justify-content: center; on the parent.

Comment: sorry mate it didn't work this is the result of the css your recommended https://imgur.com/U8kkVa0 I think I need absolute for the divs to overlap as they are not in the same div thanks though

Comment: @RitanshuSingh It could be that  I've miss interpreted your code maybe write it out and I'll see if it works?

Comment: I don't understand your project, but this trick works on every element. You can just keep you code as it is but add the following code to the element you want to center. left: 50%; and transform:translateX(-50%);

Answer (score 1):

To center any element with position property different than static, you can use the following code. However, be clear that the following code takes slightly more CPU time than other methods;

To center Horizontally

```
left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

To center vertically

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

And particularly for this answer apply `right: 0px;` on the container with fixed positioning and also apply the code to center horizontally on the element you want to center.

Comment: Hi again thanks for the help but as you can see what you're suggesting doesn't work still https://imgur.com/Za124gj

Comment: I got your problem, just put the code right: 0; to the element on which you've applied fixed positioning. Also keep the above code(code in the answer) with element you want to center.

Comment: managed to fix it not exactly how I'd like but it works thanks!

Comment: I have to predefine the width I'd rather set width at 100% and add margin left and right of 1 rem or something much nicer for scaling and minor changes in aspect ration

Answer (score 0):

So the problem appears to be with setting left a or right margin values at the edge to create a space either side like I normally would. so instead of width 100% and 1rem left/right margin (which id use as is great for scaling. I had set a preset width and implement the code above provided by @RitanshuSingh.
so my code looks like this:

```
.meal_popup {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
}

.meal_popupElement {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 35rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
    0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  z-index: 2;
}

.meal_popupBackground {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(00, 00, 00, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

preferably would like to select a margin but this works for now if you know how to get that working please post a fix.

result:
[image]